# Can a non-entangled qubit be teleported by entangling it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer, quantum-teleportation

Let's say I have a qubit that is not entangled in state $\psi$. I want to teleport this qubit by entangling it with another qubit but still getting $\psi$ back in the end.

Is this possible, or would entangling the qubit mean changing $\psi$ in a non-reversible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantum teleportation works on any qubit. It isn't restricted to only working on entangled qubits. It works on unentangled qubits.

Quantum teleportation does require the sender and receiver to have shared an EPR pair $P_{A,B}$ in order to send your qubit $|\psi\rangle$, and the teleportation process will use up $P_{A,B}$, but there is no restriction on $|\psi\rangle$.

The qubit to teleport can be entangled, unentangled, pure, mixed, being used for superdense coding, part of some other EPR pair, whatever. Teleportation works regardless.

[Here's a interactive quantum teleportation circuit](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:[[1,%22H%22],[1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22Y%5Et%22],[%22Bloch%22,%22Bloch%22,%22Bloch%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22H%22],[%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22],[1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22Z%22]]%7D) teleporting various unentangled states.

Answer (score 2):

Take a pair of qubits in a maximally entangled state $\phi=A\otimes B+B\otimes A$.  (Here $A$ and $B$ are a basis for the state space of a single qubit.) One stays with you, the other resides at the intended location.  You've therefore got two qubits --- the one you want to transport (in state $\psi$) and one of the entangled pair.

Now make an observation with eigenvectors $A\otimes A+B\otimes B$, $A\otimes A-B\otimes B$, $A\otimes B+B\otimes A$, $A\otimes B-B\otimes A$. An easy and enlightening calculation reveals that the distant qubit, depending on the outcome of the observation, is in one of four states $\phi$, $U\phi$, $V\phi$, $W\phi$, where $U,V,W$ are fixed (independent of $\phi$) unitary transformations.  Moreover, the outcome of your observation tells you which of these states the distant qubit is in.

Therefore there's a 1/4 chance you've successfully teleported.  If you haven't, you can send a message (via classical channels) telling someone at the other end to apply $U^{-1}$, $V^{-1}$ or $W^{-1}$, as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it seems I haven't communicated my question very well. I know about quantum teleportation of entangled qubits, but I was wondering whether or not the entaglement itself would change the state of the qubit to a point where you couldn't change back to the original state.

Comment: It's the observation that irreversibly changes the state of the qubit --- just as any observation would.

Comment: So the entanglement wouldn't actually change any information? If I started with $\psi$, entangled it, and teleported it I could still get $\psi$ back?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "the entanglement".  You want to teleport $X$.  You have a qubit $Y$ that is entangled with a distant qubit $Z$.  You observe the pair $(X,Y)$.   The one and only action you take is to make that observation.  That one  action is what (irreversibly) destroys the state.

Comment: Oh, so qubit X doesn't have to be entangled at all, I see. Thank you for your help.